# Spinner is not becoming Visible at the right time?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Initially spinner is Invisible.When a button is pressed downloadImage() method is called.But `spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` does not make spinner visible until `imageView.setImageBitmap(resultImage);` is executed.

> i.e `spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` is executed after image is downloaded and set to image view.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;
Bitmap resultImage;
Bitmap bitmap;
ProgressBar spinner;

public void downloadImage(View view){

    ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    try {
        resultImage = imageDownloader.execute("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png").get();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    imageView.setImageBitmap(resultImage);
    //spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.spinner);


}
public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: have u tried this-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is related to calling `get()` inside your `downloadImage` method it causes the process to wait, which is exactly what you don't want.

When you call `execute("http.....")`, it returns an AsyncTask, which you then call `get()` on,  which then waits until the result is available.  The view is not updated until the onClick listener is completed, which is after the download is complete.

[See the doc for get here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get())

change your `downloadImage` method to this.

```
public void downloadImage(View view){
    ImageDownloader imageDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
    imageDownloader.execute("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png");
}
```

and then move your view manipulations into the ImageDownloader pre/post execute methods.
    public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```